# How to render displacement of cycles material output into normal map?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, render-layers

I'm using blender to render sprites to 2d game. I'm using render layers to separate output into different layers my game engine requires, including normal map:

[image]

However, when using a texture with displacement:

[image]

...it just doesn't show up on the normal output:

[image: Normal map without displacement] [image: Rendered sprite for reference]

I suppose normal output has only geometry in it? How would I go about adding this texture to normal map?

Please note that I'm not baking sprites, I'm using full render output separated into layers. This is to enable animated normal map output.

#### EDIT:

This actually seems to work as expected in Blender 2.78a:

[image: Normals with Blender 2.78a]

This seems to be a bug in Blender 2.79.

Comment: This actually works in as expected 2.78a and fails in 2.79

Comment: In my version (2.79.1 from PPA) there is no problem. Maybe you have something in your file, can you share it? (use blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to upload the file, then paste the provided link in your question's text)

Comment: @Crantisz I have this problem in 2.79 (build 2017-09-11, 5bd8ac9) and it works fine with 2.79 (build 2017-11-05, 8a72be7) - using same config files. It does seem that there was bug and is fixed in latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in a version 2.79 (build 2017-09-11, 5bd8ac9). Same scene rendered fine in both 2.78a and latest build of 2.79 (build 2017-11-05, 8a72be7).